# What's the difference between printf("%.d", 0) and printf("%.1d", 0)?

Tags: c, io, formatting, printf, precision

I'm working on recoding `printf` and I'm blocked for a moment now with the precision flag. So I read that the default precision when type conversion specifier is `d` is 1:

[image: default precison]

So I supposed that there is no difference between `%.d` and `%.1d`, but when I test:

```
printf(".d =%.d, .1d= %.1d", 0, 0);
```

I do find one:

```
.d =, .1d= 0
```

Comment: See [C11 7.21.6.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1): `"%.d"` is equivalent to `"%.0d"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you use `.` after `%` without specifying the precision, it is set to zero.**

[From the `printf` page on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> **`.`** followed by integer number or *, or neither that specifies
>   precision of the conversion. In the case when * is used, the precision
>   is specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of
>   this argument is negative, it is ignored. **If neither a number nor *
>   is used, the precision is taken as zero.**

It defaults to `1` if you use `%d` (without `.`):

```
printf("d = %d, 1d= %1d", 0, 0);
# Output:   d = 0, 1d= 0
```

Answer (score 5):

The C18 standard - ISO/IEC 9899:2018 - (emphasize mine) states:

> "An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions, the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for the g and G conversions, or the maximum number of bytes to be written for s conversions. The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed either by an asterisk * (described later) or by an optional non negative decimal integer; **if only the period is specified, the precision is taken as zero.**  If a precision appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined."
>
> Source: C18, §7.21.6.1/4

Means `%.d` is equal to `%.0d` and with that different to `%.1d`.

---

Furthermore:

> "d,i - The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style [-]dddd. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. **The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.**"
>
> Source: C18, §7.21.6.1/8

That means if you convert a `0` value by using `%.d` in a `printf()` call, the result is guaranteed to be no characters printed (which matches to your test experience).

Answer (score 1):

When the precision is set to zero or its value is omitted like

```
printf( "%.d", x )'
```

when according to the description of the conversion specifiers d and i (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style [−]dddd.
>   The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the
>   value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is
>   expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. **The result
>   of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no
>   characters.**

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%.d\n", 0 );
    printf( "%.0d\n", 0 );
    printf( "%.1d\n", 0 );      
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0
```

That is when the precision is equal to 0 or its value is absent then if 0 is specified as an argument when nothing will be outputted.